# Is there a compiler flag so that the linker warns me about this? .h file with no .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

Quick question. I've got a project with a class with no implementation file.

Then in the AppDelegate I've got:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SomeClass.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *myProperty;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self.myProperty hello];

//    self.myProperty = [[SomeClass alloc] init]; // uncomment and fails as expected.

    return YES;
}
```

Shouldn't somebody tell me that there is no implementation file ? Some sort of warning or anything?

If I do an alloc] init] it'll not compile as expected.

That code actually compiles.

Here is the project in github.

https://github.com/nmiyasato/noImplementation

Thanks

Comment: It will fail to link if a class has no implementation. Warnings are usually for things that will compile and link fine but are likely wrong.

Comment: there should be a library file with .a extension or there should be some SDK (Framework) related to it.

Comment: That code actually compiles... i've added a sample project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This isn't detectable at compile time or at link time in Objective-C.

First, the compiler knows exactly *nothing* about "header files" or "implementation files." (This is changing a little with the new module system, but that's not what we're discussing here.)

`#import` is not handled by the compiler. It's handled by the pre-processor. It takes the file `SomeClass.h` and splats it into `AppDelegate.m` as text before the compiler even sees line one. So all the compiler has to work with is this one giant file with all the text of all the headers plus this implementation (while there is "whole module optimization" now, that's a link step, not a compile step). It doesn't have any access to the rest of the project.

So the compiler has no way to know that you haven't provided an implementation. And in ObjC, even if the compiler looked at all the code, it couldn't actually know that there's no implementation anywhere because you can add implementations at runtime. In fact, it's pretty *common* to do this. It's how all of Core Data works. The implementations also may be linked in via a shared framework (which is very common), and *may* even be linked in at runtime on OS X. Or the implementations may be in a static library, so lacking a `.m` is still unhelpful.

It's even possible that the result of `self.myProperty` is random "other thing" that is only *pretending* to be `SomeClass`. Yeah, I know that sounds crazy. Welcome to class clusters with Core Foundation bridging. That's a thing. So there might not even be an implementation in the way you're thinking. Objective-C is a pretty insanely dynamic language.

As an example, the following is legal ObjC (it even works):

```
@interface NSString (Hello)
- (void)hello;
@end

@implementation NSString (Hello)    
- (void)hello {
    NSLog(@"I'm string's Hello!");
}
@end

...
self.myProperty = (SomeClass *)@"";
[self.myProperty hello];
```

You'd think maybe the linker could figure it out, but by the time we get to the linker, all object types are `id` and all methods are just selectors and method signatures. Most of the type information is gone.

So why does this fail to link if you call `[[SomeClass alloc] init]`? First note that it does compile, it just doesn't link. The reason is that `[self.myProperty hello]` is a message to an object. The linker doesn't know or care about the type of the object. It just needs a pointer to the instance. But `[SomeClass alloc]` is a message to a class. In order to link it, the linker has to have a pointer to the class. You'll find that any message to a class that isn't implemented will create a linker error (try `[SomeClass initialize]`).

In your code nothing happens at runtime because `self.myProperty` is nil, so there's no error. That would be the same even if you had an implementation. In the vast majority of cases the lack of an implementation file is going to be caught during link because *somewhere* in your system you probably call `+alloc`. So in practice, this shouldn't come up often at all, and this rare case is extremely difficult to detect without breaking a lot of legitimate ObjC.